# How to create below UI in android xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to create a Custom dialog like below UI XML layout but i do not know how ?
these inside corned and dashed line are hard to implement to me!
please guide, prefer no library just pure code! 
[Click to see my UI layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QURh.png)

Comment: Check something like this: https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView

Comment: Tanks, but i want to create by pure code, no any library

Comment: The library uses "pure code" inside. BTW you can simply check how they achieved some of the hardest parts of the custom view and use the same logic in your code

Comment: Good suggestion to use https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView for the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Background should Be Transparent or single color ?